# How to show the reviews count on the product slider?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I did it like this but it does not show on the product slider so how can I do that?

[Display review count on Shopware product listing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73333013/display-review-count-on-shopware-product-listing-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may decorate the `ProductSliderCmsElementResolver` to alter the criteria and results of the slider element.

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolverDecorator" decorates="Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolver">
    <argument type="service" id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductSliderCmsElementResolverDecorator.inner"/>
</service>
```

```php
class ProductSliderCmsElementResolverDecorator implements CmsElementResolverInterface
{
    private CmsElementResolverInterface $decorated;

    public function __construct(CmsElementResolverInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->decorated->getType();
    }

    public function collect(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext): ?CriteriaCollection
    {
        $collection = $this->decorated->collect($slot, $resolverContext);
        
        if (!$collection) {
            return null;
        }

        foreach ($collection->all() as $criterias) {
            foreach ($criterias as $criteria) {
                $criteria->addAggregation(
                    new TermsAggregation('review_count', 'product.id', null, null, new CountAggregation('review_count', 'product.productReviews.id'))
                );
            }
        }

        return $collection->all() ? $collection : null;
    }

    public function enrich(CmsSlotEntity $slot, ResolverContext $resolverContext, ElementDataCollection $result): void
    {
        $this->decorated->enrich($slot, $resolverContext, $result);

        // results from product streams
        $entitySearchResult = $result->get('product-slider-entity-fallback_' . $slot->getUniqueIdentifier());
        if ($entitySearchResult === null) {
            // manual results
            $entitySearchResult = $result->get('product-slider_' . $slot->getUniqueIdentifier());
        }
        if ($entitySearchResult === null) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($entitySearchResult->getAggregations() as $aggregation) {
            if ($aggregation->getName() === 'review_count') {
                foreach ($aggregation->getBuckets() as $bucket) {
                    /** @var SalesChannelProductEntity $product */
                    $product = $entitySearchResult->getEntities()->get($bucket->getKey());
                    if (!$product) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $text = new TextStruct();
                    $text->setContent((string) $bucket->getResult()->getCount());
                    $product->addExtension('review_count', $text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```