# Display review count on Shopware product listing page (for variants)

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to show the product review's total count on the product listing page.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73333013/display-review-count-on-shopware-product-listing-page/) but this doesn't work for variants. The review count shows 0 for these products. I think this is because the reviews are assigned to the parent product.

How can i show the review's total count for variants?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask